# Google Classroom - How to list coursework with a given dueDate

Tags: google-classroom

Is there a way to list coursework for a given date range.  I can pull all the coursework for a class but then would have to cycle through it to get the current assignments.  I am hoping that I am just overlooking something very obvious.

Comment: Thank you to whom ever downvoted my question.  I assume that means it is simply enough that everyone should know the answer.  However, I noticed that you could not even leave a comment as to why you downvoted.  Either be constructive or don't participate.

Comment: I haven't used this before but it looks like you can do it from courses.courseWork / list found [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list). One of the orderBy options is dueDate

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question.  Yes, the courses.courseWork / list does list the assignments, but you cannot define a period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those that are interested, the only way I have figured out to do this is to also incorporate Google Calendar.  Every Google Class has a unique calendar that the assignments get saved to.  You can get the calendar id from courses and then query the calendar for a specific date or range of dates.

Answer (score 0):

Various endpoints in the API similarly don't allow filtering to certain degrees.  However, since a classroom is a fairly small package (typically <100 students, <100 assignments, etc.), cycling through as you mention shouldn't be a computational chore, which is probably why they don't offer the filtering for now.  I would think this would actually be easier conceptually (and probably computationally, because of fewer API hits) than going though calendar, but that's an interesting workaround.